# Glassfish DAS OutOfMemory with total heap usage below max heap size

Tags: performance, jvm, glassfish, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am running a big enterprise application in a Glassfish V2.1 6-instances cluster configuration (SLES 10 SP4, 64 bits Suse Linux machine with 19Gb of RAM) and the DAS machine server.log is showing some "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" errors. The heap usage report from DAS' jvm.log shows:

```
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 103488K, used 99840K [0x00002aab237c0000, 0x00002aab2a270000, 0x00002aab4e260000)
  eden space 99840K, 100% used [0x00002aab237c0000,0x00002aab29940000,0x00002aab29940000)
  from space 3648K, 0% used [0x00002aab29940000,0x00002aab29940000,0x00002aab29cd0000)
  to   space 4672K, 0% used [0x00002aab29de0000,0x00002aab29de0000,0x00002aab2a270000)
 PSOldGen        total 1398144K, used 1398143K [0x00002aaace260000, 0x00002aab237c0000, 0x00002aab237c0000)
  object space 1398144K, 99% used [0x00002aaace260000,0x00002aab237bfe70,0x00002aab237c0000)
 PSPermGen       total 107200K, used 106931K [0x00002aaaae260000, 0x00002aaab4b10000, 0x00002aaace260000)
  object space 107200K, 99% used [0x00002aaaae260000,0x00002aaab4accd98,0x00002aaab4b10000)
```

From the above we get total heap space of 1.6Gb (103488 + 1398144 + 107200 = 1608832 ~ 1.6Gb) even though the maximum allowed heap space is set to 2Gb (-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx2048m). My question is then: why isn't the JVM increasing the heap size before outputting OOM errors? How can we interpret the above heap report? I ran MAT tool on a binary heap file and got 2 leak suspects:

```
Problem suspect #1

One instance of "com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer" loaded by "<system class loader>" occupies 522,351,680 (34.12%) bytes. The instance is referenced by org.jvnet.glassfish.comms.admin.management.extensions.config.OverloadProtectionServiceConfigImpl @ 0x2aaacfe74ed0 , loaded by "com.sun.appserv.server.util.ASURLClassLoader @ 0x2aaace7fc630". The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.HashMap$Entry[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".

Keywords
java.util.HashMap$Entry[]
com.sun.appserv.server.util.ASURLClassLoader @ 0x2aaace7fc630
com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer

Problem suspect #2

140,421 instances of "net.jxta.impl.endpoint.tcp.TcpMessenger", loaded by "com.sun.appserv.server.util.ASURLClassLoader @ 0x2aaace7fc630" occupy 735,809,464 (48.07%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.util.TimerTask[]", loaded by "<system class loader>"

Keywords
java.util.TimerTask[]
com.sun.appserv.server.util.ASURLClassLoader @ 0x2aaace7fc630
net.jxta.impl.endpoint.tcp.TcpMessenger
```

Unfortunately the error occurred a few weeks ago and the machine has been restarted since so I may have lost some contextual info. I am looking for hints or explanations and try to prevent those errors. Thanks in advance for any help.

cheers

/Sam

Comment: Where is the actual OOM error? It looks more like you ran out of permgen than heap mem.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is then: why isn't the JVM increasing the heap size before outputting OOM errors?

With the JVM-options you've set (*-Xmx2048m*) the max heap space would be 2G, thats right, but you didn' set the *inital heap space option* **-Xms1024**.
This option would tell the JVM to provide the server initially with 1024MB heap space instead of increasing it slowly when its needed.

This could prevent you from getting OOM erros because sometimes the JVM does not notice some memory changes because of the GC.

Have a look at [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/12/03/glassfish-tuning-primer) to tune up your application server.

Regarding your MemLeaks:
It's hard to tell if those are *real* memory leaks or just some server classes.
To check this you could trigger a memory dump and analyze it wit e.g. [MemoryAnalyser](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Hope this helps, have Fun!

Comment: I took note and this initial heap size parameter (-Xms) should definitely be set (to max heap size value IMHO). The comment you made: "because sometimes the JVM does not notice some memory changes because of the GC" worries me though. Do you have some specific bug reference I could look into? I also noticed that the GC and heap-related JVM options have been set and tuned for the cluster instances but only partially on the server (DAS) configuration. Thanks for your insightful response.

Comment: Your right, the `-Xms` value should be set to the `-Xmx` value. Sorry, for now I don't have any references at hand (just a bug-tracker about GC not executing after multiple redeploy) but I can recommend [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4343/abeic/index.html) and [this](http://www.jroller.com/agileanswers/entry/preventing_java_s_java_lang) article about tuning especially the garbage colection. They helped me solving this in my environment! Cheers!